# Cambiar nombre de aplicación en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación creada con el Visual Studio con varios proyectos dentro. Por cada proyecto creo un ejecutable que luego voy a utilizar, el ejecutable tiene un nombre del estilo `miAplicacion.exe`, pero cuando intento abrir un archivo desde "Abrir con.." el nombre que me aparece es miAplicacion y yo querría que apareciese "Aplicación Jota" es decir un friendly name en vez de el nombre del ejecutable. ¿Se puede hacer esto desde el Visual Studio? ¿O es al generar el instalador y registrar mi aplicación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio el nombre que debería aparecer es el que especifiques como "Título" de la aplicación en la información del ensamblado.

Abre las propiedades del proyecto. En la pestaña "Aplicación" haz click en el botón "Información del ensamblado" y pon el nombre que quieras en "Título".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen está en inglés pero creo que se entiende.

Comment: Nada, lo he probado y el nombre que aparece sigue siendo el del exe

Comment: ¿Qué instalador utilizas?

Comment: Lo hago con NSIS

Comment: Lo siento. No lo conozco. Quizás alguien que haya trabajado con él...

Comment: Perdon, el .exe lo genero directamente desde el Visual el instalador general es el que hago con NSIS pero no tiene que ver.

Comment: Sí, pero al final va a ser el instalador el que va a registrar la aplicación en Windows. Lo normal es que coja el nombre de la información del ensamblado pero, si no es así, entiendo que se podrá indicar de alguna forma al preparar el paquete de instalación.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cambia el nombre de la solución, seguidamente el nombre de tu proyecto.
   En el menu de Visual, clicka en la pestaña Proyecto y selecciona las propiedades de tu proyecto.
2. En la ventana de propiedades, en el apartado de Aplicación, reemplaza el Nombre del emsamblado: y el Espacio de nombre de la raíz: por el nuevo nombre que has dado a tu solución y a tu proyecto.
3. En el supuesto caso que tengas errores de espacios de nombres en Datasets etc, reemplaza todas las anteriores referencias(anterior nombre de ensambaldo u Espacio de nombre de la raiz) con el nuevo nombre del emsamblado y/u el Espacio de nombre de la raiz.
4. Cierra Visual Studio y vete a la carpeta de tu proyecto.Allí selecciona y borra todos los archivos *.suo que encuentres.
5. Ahora deberías poder abrir de nuevo tu proyecto.
6. Esta solución, en mi caso funciona en Visual Studio 2010 con tipo de proyecto Windows Forms.